# Come si dice "content word(s)" in italiano?

Tags: word-choice

Mi sto riferendo precisamente a [questo concetto di linguistica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_word), per cui la domanda nel titolo dovrebbe essere autosufficient, e assumo non ci sia bisogno di alcuno esempio o contesto.

"Parola/e di contenuto" mi sembrerebbe una soluzione molto arronzata, ma non mi viene in mente null'altro.

Mi chiedo se esista qualche termine tecnico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credo invece che  *parola di contenuto* o *parola contenuto* vadano benissimo, vedo che questo è il termine usato in linguistica.

Ad esempio, vedi all'inizio di questa voce  della Enciclopedia  Treccani, che dice:

> Il significato di una parola può essere di vario tipo. Una prima
> distinzione è quella tra significato lessicale e significato
> grammaticale, in base alla quale le parole che compongono il lessico
> di una lingua si distinguono in due grandi gruppi: le parole contenuto
> e le parole funzione.

https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/definizione-lessicale_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/

o anche

https://doc.studenti.it/appunti/linguistica-applicata/linguistica-generale-applicata.html

Questi link usano *parola contenuto*, ma ho visto anche usato *parola di contenuto.*