# Gli avverbi sono sempre parole contenuto?

Tags: grammar

[Di recente ho chiesto come tradurre *content words* dall'Inglese all'Italiano. Risposta: *parole contenuto*.](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14131/come-si-dice-content-words-in-italiano)

[Treccani dice](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/definizione-lessicale_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) (grassetto mio)

> Una prima distinzione è quella tra significato lessicale e significato grammaticale, in base alla quale le parole che compongono il lessico di una lingua si distinguono in due grandi gruppi: le **parole contenuto** e le parole funzione. Mentre le prime (**perlopiù** verbi, nomi, aggettivi e, secondo alcuni, anche **avverbi**) forniscono il contenuto, le seconde (articoli, pronomi, congiunzioni e preposizioni; ➔ ) tendono a svolgere funzioni supplementari, come quella di indicare le relazioni esistenti tra le parole che introducono il contenuto.

ora, dato che *avverbi* non è nelle parentesi relative alle parole funzione, e anche perché quelle parentesi non iniziano con *perlopiù*, sarei portato a pensare che Treccani mi stia dicendo che gli avverbi sono *sempre* parole contenuto.

È così?

Capisco *abbastanza*, *velocemente*, ecc. Ma *così*, per esempio? Che significato/contenuto porta con sé?